Browser that automatically resumes failed downloads
I am looking for a web browser (like Firefox, Chrome, or other) that automatically tries to resume failed downloads.
My Internet connection is not very stable. Sometimes, if I'm downloading a large file (measured in gigabytes), after an hour of downloading, the download can fail. At that point, I have to manually go to the downloads section of my browser (Firefox) and resume the download manually. If the server supports resumable downloads, then Firefox will resume the download. Sometimes, it fails at this, and Firefox wipes all the existing data downloaded and sets the file to zero bytes. I don't want to have to manually resume a large download, I would like my browser to automatically resume a failed download for me.
I know I can use a download manager, but I would rather use a browser that automatically attempts to resume downloading.

Maybe you can use a browser extension like Auto Resume Downloads or auto-resume downloads to do it.
While it's not built into the browser, it's a task specific tool and not a full download manager.
